# In Shiny, how do I directly substitute source code into R function calls or statements?

Tags: r, shiny

Right now, I'm coding in Shiny, the web-app creation framework written in R, and I use the `app.R` format for my Shiny app, which mean I have two variables that I pass to `Shiny::runapp(ui, server)`. The code for the `server` looks like this:

```
#SERVER CODE: INCLUDE YOUR SOURCE FILES BELOW
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  source("mod_input.R", local=TRUE)
  source("mod_normalization.R", local=TRUE)
  source("mod_outlier.R", local=TRUE)
}
```

These source files contain code like this:

```
output$outlier_PCA <- renderPlot({
  withProgress(message='Creating PCA plot...', {
    if(!is.null(rval$outlier_rw)) {
      rwl <<- logTrans(rval$outlier_rw)
      print(mdl_pca(rwl) + ggtitle("Principal Component Analysis Graph (Retained Data)"))
    }
  })
})
```

...which is pretty standard--I output my `ggplot2` graphs to variables that are "features" of the general `output` variable that Shiny processes and sends to the output.

The other half of a Shiny app is the UI:

```
ui <- navbarPage("test app",

  ###INPUT MODULE
  tabPanel("Data Input",

    ##ROW 1
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
          #FILE UPLOAD
          tabsetPanel("Upload files",
            tabPanel("Upload Raw Data",
               fileInput("rw_file",label = "Raw Sample Counts (CSV)"),
               fileInput("srr_file", label= "Experiment-Sample Metadata (CSV) \n[Optional]"),
               fileInput("srx_file", label= "Experiment Summary (CSV) \n[Optional]"),
               actionButton("submit_raw_data", label='Submit data')
            ),
            #DATA PREVIEW
            tabPanel("Preview Raw Data",
              DT::dataTableOutput("rw_preview",  width = "auto", height="auto"),
              uiOutput("rw_preview_range"),
              uiOutput("grab_rw_preview_range")
            ),
            #NORMALIZED DATA PREVIEW
            tabPanel("Preview Normalized Data",
               DT::dataTableOutput("norm_preview",  width = "auto", height="auto"),
               uiOutput("norm_preview_range"),
               uiOutput("grab_norm_preview_range")
            )
          )
      )
    )
    ##ROW 2
  ),
  ###END INPUT MODULE

  ###OUTLIER REMOVAL MODULE
  tabPanel("Outlier Removal",
           column(4,
                  wellPanel(
                    tabsetPanel("Settings",
                                tabPanel("Filter data",
                                         sliderInput(inputId = "outlier_zscore", "Resistant Z-score Sample Threshold",
                                                     min=0, max=10.0,
                                                     value=2.0, step=0.01),
                                         actionButton(inputId = "grab_outlier_zscore", "Filter data")
                                ),
                                tabPanel("Sample Boxplot",
                                         uiOutput("outlier_preview_range") ,
                                         actionButton(inputId = "grab_outlier_preview_range", "View samples")
                                )
                    )
                  ),
                  plotOutput("outlier_PCA")
           ),
           column(8,
                  plotOutput("outlier_boxplot"),
                  plotOutput("outlier_density")
           )
  )
  ###END OUTLIER REMOVAL MODULE
)
```

Now, I want to compartmentalize each part of the UI that corresponds to a certain module in this app, but I can't simply do the same thing like I did with server and `source("filename.R", local=TRUE)`. It simply doesn't work.

**Is there another option I can use for directly substituting source code from a file directly into a R function/statement?**

Comment: A good approach for dividing this code among files would be to assign `row1 <- fluidRow(column(12... etc` (or columns, as you prefer) each in a separate file, then source each, then define the UI as `tabPanel(row1, row2, ...)` Diving beyond that into actually inserting code from other files is atypical

Comment: @DavidRobinson Ah, I see, so it would make better sense to assign variables to things like this. It... seems to work. I'm not sure. It's code is converted to HTML, so...?

Comment: The difference between `ui.R` and `server.R` in your examples is that server.R is actually executing code within a function- that's something you can source. The UI is constructing a single object (`ui`) with many nested arguments. You can't run source in the middle of an argument, but you also don't have to compute it all at once

Comment: @DavidRobinson Mmm, I see. It appears to work! If you write an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since @DavidRobinson didn't provide an answer, I will summarize his solution:

The best way to accomplish this is to simply assign the output of the UI component functions as variables, and then to directly include these variables in the larger UI function itself.

```
ui_input <- 
tabPanel("Data Input",
 ##ROW 1
 fluidRow(...and so on...


ui <- navbarPage("Shiny App",
  ui_input
)
```